# Loop through checkboxes and gather names of the ones that are checked - JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="SummaryInformation">Summary Information<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="ProductLegs">Product Legs<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="AmortizationOptions">Amortization Options<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Values">Values<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Rates">Rates<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="RatesSpecific">Rates (All-In-Rate, PV01)<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="AmortizationSchedule">Amortization Schedule<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="SponsorInfo">Sponsor/Affiliate Info<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="BorrowerInfo">Borrower Info<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="SponsorContacts">Sponsor/Affiliate Contacts<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="CashFlows">Cash Flows<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="PrePayment">Pre-Payment<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="FutureExposure">Potential Future Exposure<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="FutureExposureSpecific">Potential Future Exposure (Max Number and Date Only)<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="History">History<br />
```

I need to loop through all of these in JQuery and create an array of the names of the ones that are checked. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var names = [];
$("checkbox:checked").each(function(){
   names.push($(this).attr("name"));
})
```

you might want to add a div around the checkboxes you want this done to, so that you dont loop through ALL checkboxes on the screen.

if you did this the selector would change to:

```
$("#mydiv checkbox:checked")
```

where `mydiv` is the id of that div

Comment: How would I make this so it only searched the ones in that particular div?

Comment: Just do this.name instead of $(this).attr["name"]. No need to wrap it with jquery. it will just make it slower

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];

$('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked').each(function(){
     arr.push($(this).attr('name'));
});

alert(arr.join('-'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/):

```
$(':checked').each(function(){
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as

```
$("input:checked").each(...);
```

Here is a Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vFmNh/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use filter it's faster.

$('input').filter(function() {return this.checked})